# Writing an EXE output to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, exe

I have an EXE which will have the Output values as 0/1. The EXE is to be called via a batch file. I want the Batch file to run the EXE and write the output obtained. How is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I asume that you want to capture the output of the EXE and process that value, instead of just printing that value. Here is how you can capture the output in a variable:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('%~dp0sometool.exe') DO SET TOOLOUTPUT=%%i
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess this is more or less, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to the /F extension to the FOR loop.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('call testing.exe') DO echo %%i
```

Answer (score 0):

How does the exe write its output?  Is it just writing to the console?  If so, you can direct it to a file using > or >>.

For example:

```
C:\>dir >> dir.txt
```

Creates a text file with the output of the dir command.

">" creates a new file each time while ">>" will append to the file if it exists already.